# Use new NuxtJS app with an existing Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

The situation is, I have an existing Express API. Then my team member has his VueJS app powered by NuxtJS. We built them separately, the API and the app.

The question is, how can I integrate / SSR the Vue/NuxtJS app with my express API?

I saw and tried to follow [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459797/load-nuxt-project-to-exist-express-app) but I can't seem to make it work. The express API is launching, but I cannot find what path and how can I access the Vue/NuxtJS app.

Anyone with similar situation?

Comment: You can just launch them separately and work like normal backend and frontend

Comment: @Aldarund because of some business requirements, we need to do it that way. I think I solved it, going to try it first then comment my answer later if proven true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solution works in my case scenario, an adjustment might be needed to make it work for you.**

First is you need to create the middleware function, you can follow [the 2nd answer on this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028514/use-express-js-in-an-existing-nuxt-js-project)

My folder structure looks like this:

```
vuejs-app/
    | --- api/ <-- ( my express server folder )
    | --- assets/
    | --- ...
```

Then I added this line on my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
rootDir: __dirname,
```

because my nuxtjs.config is **outside** my api folder.

Then in your express server, install NuxtJS.

(**Note: The version of NuxtJS in your Express server should be equal to the version of your vuejs app**) This is important, because the app won't compile properly.

Then add your nuxtjs middleware as your express middleware.

```
import nuxtjs-middleware from "/path/to/your/nuxts-middleware"
app.use(nuxtjs-middleware);
```

After that start your express api server.

**Additional Note:**

1. You might also need to adjust your api endpoints ( or your app to use your endpoint).
2. This works in my scenario, you might need to approach based on your scenario.
3. I'm not a node/express/nuxtjs expert, I just solved this by trial-and-error approach. There might be a better approach out there, but as of the time of writing, this approach solves my problem.